# Android:Only first image is displayed in Recycler View in emulator

Tags: android-recyclerview

I am trying to display a Recycler View using the emulator but it is showing only first image.

Here are few things which I tried after a lot of research:

1. Used "wrap_content" instead of "match_constraint"
2. Tried to reduce the resolution of images
3. Moved images in 'mipmap' folder

But none of the solutions worked.

I am hoping that if one image is displayed that means there should not be any problem with the code.
Is there any problem with the emulator?
I am new to android development, detailed answers will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
activity_main.xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="87dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Categories"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/categoryListView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:divider="@null"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />
```

category_list_item.xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/categoryImage"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/hatimage"
    tools:srcCompat="@drawable/hatimage" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/categoryName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/hats"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/categoryImage"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/categoryImage"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/categoryImage"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

here is the code for the adapter:

```
class CategoryRecycleAdapter(val context:Context,val categories:List<Category>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryRecycleAdapter.Holder>() {

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Holder?, position: Int) {
    holder?.bindCategory(categories[position],context)
}



override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return categories.count()
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): Holder {
val view = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        .inflate(R.layout.category_list_item, parent, false)
return Holder(view)

}
inner class Holder(itemView: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

    val categoryImage = itemView?.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.categoryImage)
    val categoryName = itemView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.categoryName)

    fun bindCategory(category:Category, context:Context){
        val resourceId = context.resources.getIdentifier(category.image,
                "drawable",context.packageName)
        categoryImage?.setImageResource(resourceId)
        categoryName?.text = category.title
    }
}
}
```

Code for populating list of items:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    var adapter = CategoryRecycleAdapter(this,DataService.categories)
    categoryListView.adapter = adapter

    val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    categoryListView.layoutManager = layoutManager
    categoryListView.setHasFixedSize(true)
}
}
```

Comment: Please add your code for the adapter and code for populating the list of items used in the recyclerview.

Comment: Have you checked if there is actually more than 1 item in your `DataService.categories` list that is used in the adapter?

Comment: Yes.I used same data structure for list view and it displayed all the items correctly.But in Recycler view it is showing only one item.

Comment: Could you post full XML code of your `category_list_item.xml`? The root layout is missing.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for pointing out. I was actually checking 'layout_height' in 'Image_View' and did not check 'root layout'. Now I changed 'layout_height' in root layout to "wrap_content" and its working fine.Thanks.@plaskoff

here is my updated root layout xml code

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
`
```